# Tracing latencies for querying MongoDB using MongoDB java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm doing a perf test to analyze the performance of a application which uses the MongoDB. The application is written in java and it uses the MongoDB java driver to connect to cloud MongoDB instance.

I want specifically to analyze the performance of the following code line.

```
collection.find(parseSearchQueryDirect(searchQuery)).skip(start).limit(offset);
```

So, I need to trace the network latency, connect time and actual query processing time for the above code line.

Is there a way to do this with mongoDB java driver or using any other tool??

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver/reference/monitoring/).

> actual query processing time for the above code line.

`Command Monitoring` section.

> connect time

`Connection Pool Monitoring` section.

> network latency

`Cluster Monitoring` section. NOTE: In `ClusterDescriptionChangedEvent` and in turns in `newDescription` you can see `getServerDescriptions` that will provide the current state of the used servers each of them in particularly will include `roundTripTimeNanos` that will mean average latency (RTT).

Comment: it seems in the `command monitoring` it shows the total time, including network latency. what I need is the actual time taken for processing the query in mongoDB server side.

Comment: then you can see it only in the server logs